# XYTools truncating decimals on export to excel

Tags: qgis

Is there some sort of setting to prevent XYTools from truncate decimals when exporting a shapefile to excel?

I live in Sweden hand we normally use comma as decimal point. Even if I change the setting both on system level as in Excel - XYTools still truncate decimals.